# Fatal error occured upon installing weblogic server 11g 10.3.6 (jar) on windows 7

Tags: weblogic11g

[Error appears when running jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7fsL.gif)

I want to install Oracle form developer 11g, for that i have to install Weblogic server 11g but it gives fatal error upon installing , jdk 1.7.0_80 64 bit installed.Snap is attached for reference...can any one help me finding the solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by deleting oracle and java instances because i have install jdk 1.7 and oracle developer 10g contains jdk 1.4,so there is an issue in java versions..because of that when i run weblogic.jar file,it gives an error

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your java version. 1.7.0_11
2. Run cmd as Adminsnitrator

   %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar wls1036_generic.jar -mode=GUI -log=wlslog.log